# "END PART" Statement in NOTAM

Tags: notam

Here's yet another installment of "how fun it is to parse NOTAM". ;-)

Statements like "END PART 2 OF 2" are quite common in the E) item of NOTAM, however, the following has triggered a red light on my parser:

```
D3616/22 NOTAMN
Q) EDGG/QRTCA/IV/BO /W /000/100/5003N00804E012
A) EDGG PART 2 OF 2 B) 2211160800 C) 2211181800
D) NOV 16 0800-2200, NOV 17 0500-2200, NOV 18 0500-1800
E) - FLTS CONDUCTED ENTIRELY UNDER IFR DEP/DEST FRANKFURT/MAIN EDDF,
FRANKFURT-HAHN EDFH AND RAMSTEIN ETAR (CHANGE PROCEDURES ARE NOT
ALLOWED) WHICH FULFIL THE ICAO STANDARDS LAID DOWN IN ANNEX 17
(SAFEGUARDING INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION AGAINST ACTS OF UNLAWFUL
INTERFERENCE) OR REGULATION (EC) NO. 300-2008 OF THE EUROPEAN
PARLIAMENT AND THE COUNCIL OF 11 MARCH 2008. THE TERM -CHANGE
PROCEDURES- REFERS TO ALL FLTS THAT ARE CONDUCTED WHOLLY OR PARTLY
UNDER VISUAL FLIGHT RULES (Y AND Z FLIGHT PLANS).
TRAINING FLIGHTS, PHOTO AND CALIBRATION FLIGHTS (INCLUDING UNDER
INSTRUMENT FLIGHT RULES) ARE NOT ALLOWED.
PRIOR ENTERING, LEAVING OR TRANSITING THE AIRSPACE ALL AUTHORISED VFR
FLTS SHALL REPORT TO THE POLICE OF HESSEN. THE PROCEDURES TO BE USED
FOR THIS WILL BE COMMUNICATED BY THE POLICE VIA THE APPROPRIATE
CHANNELS. ALL AUTHORISED VFR FLTS SHALL MAINTAIN CONTINUOUS
AIR-GROUND VOICE COMMUNICATION WATCH ON FREQ 135.600MHZ (POLICE INFO)
WHILE FLYING WITHIN THE RESTRICTED AREA. CROSSING APPROVAL IN
CONJUNCTION WITH SECTION 17 LUFTVO WILL NOT BE GRANTED.
F) GND G) FL100
END PART 2 OF 2
CREATED: 15 Nov 2022 15:42:00
SOURCE: EUECYIYN
```

In this case it's not part of the E) item, but squeezed in after the G) item and the meta data CREATED and SOURCE.

There is no mention of "END PART" in Doc 8126, so the only place I see it fit is the free form E) item. However, after grepping a few thousand NOTAM, I couldn't find another example which contains both "END PART" and a G) item.

I assume, it's been misplaced in this case. Am I right?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Yuri Sucupira Shamelessly pinging you since you're a former NOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not part of any *particular* item. Rather it is a general informational pointer than the NOTAM is so long it has spread across two separate issuances.

From the FAA's Defense Internet NOTAM Service I pulled this text:

> D3616/22 NOTAMN
> **Q)** EDGG/QRTCA/IV/BO /W /000/100/5003N00804E012
> **A)** EDGG ***PART 1 OF 2*** **B)** 2211160800 **C)** 2211181800
> **D)** NOV 16 0800-2200, NOV 17 0500-2200, NOV 18 0500-1800
> **E)** TEMPO RESTRICTED AREA EDR RHEINGAU ESTABLISHED 495537N 0075944E -
> CLOCKWISE ALONG THE ARC OF A CIRCLE 5NM AROUND 500000N 0075600E -
> 500423N 0075215E - 501023N 0080916E - CLOCKWISE ALONG THE ARC OF A
> CIRCLE 5NM AROUND 500600N 0081300E - 500131N 0081627E -
> 495919N 0081013E - 495936N 0081003E - 495728N 0080400E -
> 495708N 0080400E - 495537N 0075944E.
> ALL FLTS ARE PROHIBITED IN THE RESTRICTED AREA EDR RHEINGAU. THE
> FOLLOWING FLTS ARE EXEMPTED FROM THE FLIGHT RESTRICTIONS:
> - FLTS BY STATE AIRCRAFT RELATED TO THE G7-CONFERENCE AT ELTVILLE,
> - FLTS OF THE GERMAN ARMED FORCES,
> - FLTS OF THE UNITED STATES ARMED FORCES WITH DEP/DEST WIESBADEN
> ETOU,
> - ACTUAL POLICE MISSION FLTS AND FLTS ON BEHALF OF THE POLICE
> - FLTS ON RESCUE AND DISASTER PREVENTION MISSIONS,
> - AMBULANCE FLTS,
> - FLTS BY MODEL AIRCRAFT AND UNMANNED AIRCRAFT SYSTEMS AT A DISTANCE
> MORE OF THAN 1NM FROM 500235N 0080247E, TAKING ACCOUNT OF THE
> REGULATIONS OF SECTION 21H OF THE GERMAN AVIATION REGULATION LUFTVO
> AND UNLESS THEY DO NOT FLY ABOVE AN ALTITUDE OF 120M ABOVE GROUND
> ***END PART 1 OF 2***
> CREATED: 15 Nov 2022 15:42:00
> SOURCE: EUECYIYN

> D3616/22 NOTAMN
> **Q)** EDGG/QRTCA/IV/BO /W /000/100/5003N00804E012
> **A)** ***EDGG PART 2 OF 2*** **B)** 2211160800 **C)** 2211181800
> **D)** NOV 16 0800-2200, NOV 17 0500-2200, NOV 18 0500-1800
> **E)** - FLTS CONDUCTED ENTIRELY UNDER IFR DEP/DEST FRANKFURT/MAIN EDDF,
> FRANKFURT-HAHN EDFH AND RAMSTEIN ETAR (CHANGE PROCEDURES ARE NOT
> ALLOWED) WHICH FULFIL THE ICAO STANDARDS LAID DOWN IN ANNEX 17
> (SAFEGUARDING INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION AGAINST ACTS OF UNLAWFUL
> INTERFERENCE) OR REGULATION (EC) NO. 300-2008 OF THE EUROPEAN
> PARLIAMENT AND THE COUNCIL OF 11 MARCH 2008. THE TERM -CHANGE
> PROCEDURES- REFERS TO ALL FLTS THAT ARE CONDUCTED WHOLLY OR PARTLY
> UNDER VISUAL FLIGHT RULES (Y AND Z FLIGHT PLANS).
> TRAINING FLIGHTS, PHOTO AND CALIBRATION FLIGHTS (INCLUDING UNDER
> INSTRUMENT FLIGHT RULES) ARE NOT ALLOWED.
> PRIOR ENTERING, LEAVING OR TRANSITING THE AIRSPACE ALL AUTHORISED VFR
> FLTS SHALL REPORT TO THE POLICE OF HESSEN. THE PROCEDURES TO BE USED
> FOR THIS WILL BE COMMUNICATED BY THE POLICE VIA THE APPROPRIATE
> CHANNELS. ALL AUTHORISED VFR FLTS SHALL MAINTAIN CONTINUOUS
> AIR-GROUND VOICE COMMUNICATION WATCH ON FREQ 135.600MHZ (POLICE INFO)
> WHILE FLYING WITHIN THE RESTRICTED AREA. CROSSING APPROVAL IN
> CONJUNCTION WITH SECTION 17 LUFTVO WILL NOT BE GRANTED.
> **F)** GND **G)** FL100
> ***END PART 2 OF 2***
> CREATED: 15 Nov 2022 15:42:00
> SOURCE: EUECYIYN

You can see that Items Q through D are duplicated at the beginning of *each* NOTAM, except that in the first NOTAM Item A is "EDGG PART 1 OF 2" while in the second NOTAM Item A is "EDGG PART 2 OF 2."

Comment: Great you found these examples. It's fascinating how "creative" some NOF are in adding stuff nowhere close to Doc 8126. Knowing that, I'll just find and deal with such part markers about anywhere in the payload before parsing the rest... which should take care of it once and for all. Thanks a lot!